# Jwt login with spring boot and angular

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, jwt

First time posting, please excuse any mistakes in the question.

I'm building a simple website with spring boot and angular and implemented a jwt login using some help from the internet. I can't seem to make it work because the backend is not receiving the username and password credentials when logging in. Below is part of my code:

The spring boot security configuration class. When configure method is triggered, it prints out that the username and password sent are null.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/posts", "/api/forums").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/api/auth/login")
                .failureHandler(new AuthenticationFailureHandler(){
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
                        String email = request.getParameter("email");
                        String error = exception.getMessage();
                        System.out.println("A failed login attempt with email: " + email + " and password: " + request.getParameter("password") + ". Reason: " + error);
                    }
                })
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    protected PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Jwt support classes

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7858869558953243875L;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2550185165626007488L;

    public static final long JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY = 2*60*60;

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private byte[] secret;

    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date getIssuedAtDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getIssuedAt);
    }

    public Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(secret)).build().parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
        return expiration.before(new Date());
    }

    private Boolean ignoreTokenExpiration(String token) {
        return false;
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return doGenerateToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY*1000)).signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(secret), SignatureAlgorithm.HS512).compact();
    }

    public Boolean canTokenBeRefreshed(String token) {
        return (!isTokenExpired(token) || ignoreTokenExpiration(token));
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}
```

These snippets are part of the auth controller and service classes which are triggered when a post request with login credentials is made. Debugging mysql here also shows that the request username and password are null. LoginRequest and LoginResponse used here just have username, password and username, jwtToken fields respectively.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    private final AuthService authService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(AuthService authService) {
        this.authService = authService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> login(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) throws Exception {
        LoginResponse jwtResponse = authService.login(request);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(jwtResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

```
public LoginResponse login(LoginRequest request) throws Exception {
        authenticate(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword());
        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(request.getUsername());
        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        return new LoginResponse(userDetails.getUsername(), token);
    }

private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
    Objects.requireNonNull(username);
    Objects.requireNonNull(password);
    try {
        Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);
    } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
        throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
    }
}
```

Why are the credentials passed null? This is a backend issue because I checked with postman with no association with frontend code. I tried to send the body with different types like json, xxx-form encoded etc, but nothing seems to work.
Here an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JEID.png) of the postman request.
Is there something wrong with my code? How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please give the request URL, headers and method used to hit.

Comment: @Gopikrishna I've edited the question and added the controller class to provide you with the request url and method

Comment: I need to know how you are sending the request.

Comment: @Gopikrishna I added an image of the postman request.

Comment: Are you trying to get jwt token on passing username, password or are you trying to do form login.

Comment: @Gopikrishna I'm new to web development so I don't quite understand what you're asking, can you elaborate?

Comment: No issues friend, can you remove the filter and check if you are able to get the details in  LoginRequest  in the controller

Comment: @Gopikrishna I tried not invoking filter from SecurityConfiguration class but still the same result of passed parameters being null in debug output

Comment: @Gopikrishna I just found out that the login method in auth service is called before ever calling the login method in the controller class. I don't know why that is happening because I only call the auth service login only at one place in the code and that is in the controller. Do you know if maybe the security configuration class or the jwt helper classes I have call the auth service login method on it's own?

Comment: That's why I asked you to check by removing the security filter 

Comment: @Gopikrishna Even if I comment out all of security configuration class, the jwtTokenFIlter is being called. Do you know why that is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Comment all the code in  configure method in SecurityConfiguration class and  try.